# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response') error is raised when reading fixture file data in cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress, fixtures

Actually I have searched many times, but I couldn't find the solution. I have tried to read from fixture file users' data, the first entity will be read successfully, but when trying to read the other data in the fixture file, the error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')" is raised.

Code:

js file (test case file)

```
it("ValidateOnMsgAfterLogin", function(){ 

 
    
cy.fixture("UserCredential").then((usersBundle)=>{
  
    usersBundle.forEach((userBundle)=>{
    cy.visit("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com");
    cy.wait(6000);
// action

cy.get('[name="username"]').type(userBundle.username);

cy.get('[type="password"]').type(userBundle.password);
cy.get(".oxd-button.oxd-button--medium.oxd-button--main.orangehrm-login-button").click();




    if(userBundle.username=="Admin" && userBundle.password=="admin123"){
        cy.get(".oxd-text.oxd-text--h6.oxd-topbar-header-breadcrumb-module").as("Msg");
       cy.get("@Msg").should("have.text", "Dashboard");

         // cy.get(".oxd-userdropdown-tab").click(); // span
         cy.get(".oxd-userdropdown-img").click();
          cy.get("a").contains("Logout").click();
       
    }

    else{
cy.get(".oxd-text oxd-text--p.oxd-alert-content-text").contains("Invalid credentials").should("equal", userBundle.message);
    }



});

});




});
```

fixture file

```
[
    {
        "username": "Admin",
        "password": "admin123",
        "message": "PIM"
      
    },

    {
        "username": "Admin1",
        "password": "admin12",
        "message": "PIM"
        
    },

    {
        "username": "Admin3",
        "password": "admin123",
        "message": "PIM"
    
    }


]
```

Comment: What's the stack trace - since `response` isn't in your code, looks like it's coming from Cypress. May be a bug, or may be a work-around.